# Print date on all log lines with SLF4J

Tags: slf4j

In my project date are displayed on some lines but i want date to be displayed on all lines
can any one help

Answer (score 3):

SLF4J is the API.  You need to configure the logging backend you use to do this.  Typical examples are log4j or logback.

Answer (score 3):

Slf4j is the API. You need to use a logging framework with it.
This is how you would do it with using slf4j-log4j.jar

In your log4j.properties, use something like this as the configuration.

```
log4j.logger.com.myapp=INFO, stdout
log4j.additivity.com.myapp=false

log4j.appender.stdout=org.apache.log4j.ConsoleAppender  
log4j.appender.stdout.Threshold=INFO  
log4j.appender.stdout.layout=org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout  
log4j.appender.stdout.layout.ConversionPattern=%d{ABSOLUTE} [%t] %5p %c{1}:%L - %m%n
```

Here your application classes are assumed to be in com.myapp.* and the logging output is directed to stdout.

The ***%d*** appender corresponds to date.

You can see the meaning of the other appenders used [in the log4j Pattern Layout docs](http://logging.apache.org/log4j/1.2/apidocs/org/apache/log4j/PatternLayout.html)

Answer (score 2):

If you are using log4j as back end loggin. Configure log4j.properties file like [This](http://www.mkyong.com/logging/log4j-log4j-properties-examples/).

Answer (score 1):

As everyone said, SL4J is an API and so you need **to specify the implementation** to help you. So if you choose logback as implementation, you can simply change your **logback.xml** as follow:

Locate the `<pattern>` in your file and add %d{yyyy-MM-dd} in the begging of it's value. So if you had:

```
  <pattern>%-5level - %msg%n</pattern>
```

you would change it with this :

```
  <pattern>%d{yyyy-MM-dd} %-5level - %msg%n</pattern>
```

You can add time by using HH,mm and ss : *%d{yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss}*